# How to attach to parentView while using fragments?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have followed [this tutorial](http://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html) and its working great. In my fragment's view there are some buttons which I have some `onClick` assigned to. For example I have a button like:

```
<ImageButton
 android:onClick="doSomething">
</ImageButton>
```

While creating the rootView I use the following code:

```
 @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ViewGroup rootView = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(
            R.layout.fragment_screen_slide_page, container, false);

    return rootView;
}
```

I did some googling and found out the last parameter is for attach to parentView and I have set it to true. But the parent view is container. Where does this container point to?
Where should I write the function 'doSomething'?

Comment: Why dont you take the reference object from the ImageButton and add click listener inside the onCreateView() by pointing from rootView object

Comment: @noundla Yeah that is possible. But I am just learning the concept. It would be easy and structured the other way right? There must be someway to bind the viewGroup and FragmentActivity.

Comment: I assume this would be difficult while using fragments. Because at a certain time we may need to remove and add the fragments. Also, that method will work with the Activity. So better to continue by using listeners.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I did some googling and found out the last parameter is for attach to
>   parentView and I have set it to true.

Don't set it to `true`. In the `onCreateView()` you'll create the view for the fragment and return it and Android will attach that view to the layout on its own(what the documentation says).

> Where does this container point to?

If not null it will be the layout where the fragment's view will be added, generally used for generating the proper `LayoutParams` for the newly inflated view.

> Where should I write the function 'doSomething'?

As the buttons using the `onClick` attribute will be part of the fragment layout you should remove the `onClick` attribute from the layout and set the `OnClickListener` in code on the buttons. Android will search for the `doSomething()` method at the `Activity` level so you can't receive the on click event directly in the fragment.

Comment: I understand that it cannot receive the onClick event directly in the fragment. But there is a FragmentActivity that is creating the fragment. Is there any way to route the events to that activity?

Comment: @GeoPaul The `Activity` could send the event to the fragment if this is what you want. You'd implement the `doSomething()` method in the `Activity` and in the `doSomething()` method you'll look for the target fragment and call a method on that fragment letting it know what happened. But this would just complicate things and listeners in the fragment is a better idea.

Comment: Okay I will use OnClickListeners. But if there is any better way, let me know